# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ThreeSixty is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, elementor

I have a wordpress site and on the homepage I have a Header in Elementor and a 360 image plugins, without the active header works perfectly without errors, but when the header I made in Elementor is active the 360 ​​degree image does not work and shows this error in the console `Uncaught TypeError: $ (...). ThreeSixty is not a function`, how do I fix it? The website is [Iwo 12](https://iwo12.com.br/)

```js
<!--SPV--><script type="text/javascript">//SPV
(function($) {
  var product_192346_houzH5 = $('#threesixty-slider-192346_houzH5').ThreeSixty({
  totalFrames: 50,
  endFrame: 0,
  currentFrame: 50,
  imgList: '.threesixty-images-192346_houzH5',
  progress: '.threesixty-spinner-192346_houzH5',
  preview: '.threesixty-preview-192346_houzH5',
  images: ['https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/1.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/2.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/3.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/4.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/5.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/6.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/7.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/8.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/9.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/10.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/12.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/13.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/14.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/15.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/16.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/17.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/18.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/19.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/20.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/21.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/23.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/24.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/25.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/26.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/27.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/28.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/29.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/30.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/31.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/32.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/34.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/35.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/36.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/37.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/38.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/39.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/40.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/41.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/42.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/43.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/44.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/45.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/46.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/47.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/48.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/49.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/50.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/51.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/52.jpg','https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/53.jpg'],
  height: 0,
  width: 1280,
  navigation: false,
  drag: true,
  showCursor: true,
  interval: 40,
  speedMultiplier: 7,
  monitorInt: 10,
    onReady: function() {
   $("#threesixty-slider-192346_houzH5").removeClass('threesixty-loading');
        }
   });
   }(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: Have you loaded the ThreeSixty plugin?

Comment: I'd guess the ThreeSixty script hasn't been loaded at the point you try to run that. Can you put that into a jQuery document ready handler, or an elementor/frontend/init_complete or similar if one exists?

Comment: Can you post a link to a page (in your site) with a working ThreeSixty plugin?

Comment: And which plugin exactly are you using for the 360 effect?

Comment: I followed your steps, added the plugin and inserted `<script src="https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/plugins/smart-product-viewer/includes/js/threesixty.min.js"></script>` in wordpress header.php, but now it's giving the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined". [https://iwo12.com.br/](https://iwo12.com.br/)

Answer (score 0):

I just went to your website, and checked what was up. Your jQuery objects don't have the ThreeSixty method because you never loaded the threesixty.js addon. There is no `<script src="https://*somethingsomething*/jquery.threesixty.js"></script>` in your webpage. Download the plugin, and add it as a dependency.

Also, another critical thing, `it's $(...).threeSixty` not `it's $(...).ThreeSixty`. The first letter is *lowercase*.

Comment: I followed your steps, added the plugin and inserted <script src="https://iwo12.com.br/wp-content/plugins/smart-product-viewer/includes/js/threesixty.min.js"></script>  in wordpress header.php, but now it's giving the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined". [https://iwo12.com.br/](https://iwo12.com.br/)